# How to solve the error "Conversion from collation utf8mb3_unicode_ci into utf8mb4_unicode_ci impossible for parameter" in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, character-encoding

We have a table in our laravel application, schema looks like so

```
1   id  bigint(20) unsigned NULL    NULL    NO  NULL    auto_increment      
2   viewed  tinyint(1)  NULL    NULL    NO  1           
3   type    varchar(191)    utf8    utf8_unicode_ci YES NULL            
4   url longtext    utf8    utf8_unicode_ci YES NULL            
5   p_id    varchar(191)    utf8    utf8_unicode_ci NO  NULL            
6   client_id   varchar(191)    utf8    utf8_unicode_ci NO  NULL        clients(id) 
7   created_at  timestamp   NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
8   updated_at  timestamp   NULL    NULL    YES NULL
```

And we log the views in this table with the landing page URL like so
// add views to views log table

```
DB::table('client_p_views_log_30days')->insert([
    'client_id'     => $client_id,
    'p_id'  => $p_id,
    'type'          => $type,
    'url'           => $landing_page,
    'created_at'    => now()->toDateTimeString(),
    'updated_at'    => now()->toDateTimeString()
]);
```

database.php config for charset and collation

```
'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'),
'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'),
```

We have been receiving this error in our logs after upgrading to mysql 8.0

```
[2024-02-07 12:07:12] production.ERROR: PoptinAPI->newViewsCount()->Exception {
    "client_id": "3dae67a03936e",
    "p_id": "5486bde1f0d03",
    "Exception": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3988 Conversion from collation utf8mb3_unicode_ci into utf8mb4_unicode_ci impossible for parameter (SQL: insert into `client_p_views_log_30days` (`client_id`, `p_id`, `type`, `url`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (hfafafhah, agadfsgag, desktop, https://test.com/-testfoo/, 2024-02-07 12:07:12, 2024-02-07 12:07:12))"
} []
```

We believe its because of the emoji  in the url part
As you can see in our table schema, the column is already utf8_unicode_ci so we are not sure how we can solve this

We have tried doing

```
'url' => mb_convert_encoding($landing_page, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES'),
```

But the emoji turns to

```
https://test.com/ð-testfoo/
```

And we don't know if we can get it back from there
Anyone else encountered this issue and knows how to solve that error? Any help is appreciated

Comment: whats the output if you run in mysql `SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'client_p_views_log_30days';`

Comment: Check connection charset and collation (`SELECT @@character_set_connection, @@collation_connection;`). Also this is strange that the values in the query are not enclosed with single quote chars.

Comment: *schema looks like so* Your columns uses charset `utf8mb3` and collation `utf8_unicode_ci` already. Changes in `database.php` cannot alter this, you'd convert your structure explicitly with according ALTER TABLE statement(s).

Comment: Supposing `$landing_page = "https://test.com/-testfoo/";` try `mb_convert_encoding( $landing_page, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');` rather than `mb_convert_encoding( $landing_page, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');`…

Answer (score 0):

The emoji  cannot be represented in `CHARACTER SET utf8mb3`.  Please add more of the steps that led to where you are.

Do `SELECT HEX(URL) FROM ...` so we can see what was stored.  From that, we may be able to suggest a next step.

I doubt if *any* conversion function (`mb_*` or otherwise) will help.